# Visual Studio reinstall on different drive

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013

I want to reinstall Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate on different drive. The thing is I cannot change default path. Three dots are gray. Is there any way to fix it? Maybe I have to change some key in registry?

Comment: did you uninstall it first?

Comment: Sort of. I was unable to uninstall it, because it was installed on a drive which letter changed. So I couldn't uninstall it properly.

Comment: Use "vs_setup /uninstall /force" to clean the previous install, if that doesn't work, you'll need to do a clean install of the machine or change the drive letter back.

Answer (score 0):

for set custom install location in vs, run installation with this command:

**vs_ultimate.exe /CustomInstallPath** "*your path*"